# CSV File too big, need to split it into smaller ones

Tags: csv, split

I´m having trouble working with a big CSV File (4.000.000 rows aprox) and i´m looking for a way to divided such file into smaller ones.

Thank you for any ideas you could provide.

Comment: CSV is not synonymous with Excel.

Comment: What kind of split do you have in mind? Just "packages with n consecutive rows" or somehow sorted or categorised?

Comment: the split that i`m looking for is several csv files with the same headers basically, could be for example 4 files with 1.000.000 rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't mention which operating system you're using. In UNIX/Linux systems, there's the `split` command, you can use it as follows to split a file into chunks of two lines:

```
Prompt> split -l 2 file.txt testfile
Prompt> ls -ltra
...
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user   64 Dec 22 15:47 testfileaa
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user   64 Dec 22 15:47 testfileab
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user    1 Dec 22 15:47 testfileac
...
```

In case you're working with Windows, you might install a WSL app (Windows Subsystem for Linux), which installs a Linux-like program on your computer, giving you access to all the wonders of Linux commandline :-)

As correctly mentioned by [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1431720/robert), the second file does not contain the headers, but a simple `head -n 1 testfile` can handle this.

Comment: Hello and thank you, im using windows at the moment, very kind of you

Comment: @NelsonRomero: You're welcome. If you want to proceed with WSL, you can download it from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install

Comment: This also doesn't understand CSV and loses the headers; only the first file keeps the headers.

Comment: @Robert: you're right, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

You can use two great cli apps, that work also in windows: [miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/) and/or [qsv](https://github.com/jqnatividad/qsv#installation).

### Miller command

```
mlr --csv split -n 1000000 input.csv
```

### QSV command

```
qsv split -s 1000000 ./ input.csv
```

Comment: mlr --csv split -n 10 file.csv
mlr: verb "split" not found. Please use "mlr --help" for a list.

Comment: @llama what's your mlr version? `mlr --version` In the current version you have it https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.9.0/reference-verbs/index.html#split

Comment: It was version 6.0.0. I got version 6.9.0 and your example worked just fine. Annoyingly the apt-get is pointing at v6.0.0 with the default repos.

Answer (score 2):

There are many other ways to work with similarly sized CSV files.

Following assumes that you must use Excel to work with this file.

Use Data>Get & Transform Data>From Text/CSV

After you have selected the file, select 'Transform Data' to open the query in the Power Query editor.

From here, you can either simply use Home>Close & Load To> and configure like this:

[image]

After this you will be able to manipulate the data in the Power Pivot Data Model and use Pivot Tables and Pivot Charts to analyse the data.

Alternatively, if you must load the data to the worksheet, you can filter the data to a manageable size in the Power Query editor before using Home>Close & Load and selecting 'Table'.

If you really must actually split the data, you can create separate queries that reference the main query, each of which has a filter on some column.

In the power query editor, right-click the query you created on the file, and select 'Reference'.

[image]

This will create a new query you can filter and load as described above.

You can repeat this as many times as you want.